# How to find checked event in a checkbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to execute a function on clicking a check box. For that I am using the following code but it is not working can anyone find whats the problem with this code?

```
$('#selectAll').click(function(){
     alert("hi");
});
```

HTML

```
<th><input type="checkbox" name="selectl" value="ON" id="selectAll"/></th>
```

Comment: Post the HTML markup of your checkbox.

Comment: Is your code within a `$(document).ready` handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('#selectAll').change(function(){ 
        alert("value changed");
    });
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsadasivan/Bgz5E/).

Answer (score 2):

I tried this example below and it is working with the latest jquery version.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#chk").change(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var checked = $this.is(':checked');
            if (checked) {
                alert('checked');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selectAll').bind('change',function(){ 
    alert("hi");
});
```

Use 'change' instead! [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zc9hK/)